# How to remove repetition in output results in this code

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

```
public class ValidInvalidNodes {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] arr = { 
            { 5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },             
            { 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 },        
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },  
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0 },  
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, -1, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, -1 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, -1 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, -1 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5 }, 
    };
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
                position = j;

                if (arr[position][j] == 5)

                    System.out.print(" Valid Static Node V" + j + " \n");

            }
            if (arr[i][j] == -1) {
                position = j;

                if (arr[position][j] == 5)

                    System.out.print(" InValid Static Node V" + j + " \n");
            }
            if (arr[i][j] == -1) {
                position = j;

                if (arr[position][j] == 55)

                    System.out.print(" InValid Mobile Node V" + j + " \n");
            }

            if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
                position = j;

                if (arr[position][j] == 55)

                    System.out.print(" Valid Mobile Node V" + j + " \n");  

            }

        }
    }
    // System.out.println("");
}

}
```

Output:

```
Valid Static Node V1 
 Valid Static Node V2 
 Valid Static Node V3 
 Valid Static Node V4 
 InValid Static Node V5 
 InValid Static Node V6 
 Valid Static Node V7 
 Valid Static Node V8 
 Valid Static Node V9 
 Valid Mobile Node V10 
 InValid Static Node V11 
 InValid Mobile Node V12 
 InValid Static Node V16 
 InValid Static Node V16 
 InValid Static Node V13 
 InValid Static Node V13 
 Valid Static Node V14 
 Valid Static Node V14 
 Valid Static Node V14 
 Valid Static Node V14 
 InValid Static Node V15 
 InValid Static Node V15 
 InValid Static Node V16 
 InValid Static Node V17 
 InValid Static Node V18 
 InValid Static Node V18 
 InValid Static Node V18
```

Comment: what is your concrete question?

Comment: I guess you want every error to only be output once. In THat case instead of directly printing the errors save them in a Set and print that Sets content after your done filling it.

Comment: This isn't a good way to ask question from community. [Please visit how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh, and also: Please don't add an unnecessary C-Tag to a java question.

Comment: @Stultuske my problem is to remove repetition of results in the out put. you can see in the output:  InValid Static Node V16 
 InValid Static Node V16 
 InValid Static Node V13 
 InValid Static Node V13 
 Valid Static Node V14 
 Valid Static Node V14 
 Valid Static Node V14 
 Valid Static Node V14 InValid Static Node V18 
 InValid Static Node V18 
 InValid Static Node V18

Comment: @Ali the numbers are part of the ouput. technically, there is no repetition of results.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 1):

You could put all your lines in a `java.util.LinkedHashSet<String>`. A `Set` means it will only keep distinct items. The reason we'll use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a regular `HashSet` is to retain the input-order.

After adding them all to the set, we print them.

Here a modification of your code:

```
int[][] arr = { 
        { 5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },             
        { 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 },        
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },  
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0 },  
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 55, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, -1, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, -1 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, -1 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, -1 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5 }, 
};
java.util.Set<String> outputLines = new java.util.LinkedHashSet<>();
int position = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
            position = j;

            if (arr[position][j] == 5)
                outputLines.add("Valid Static Node V" + j);
        }
        if (arr[i][j] == -1) {
            position = j;

            if (arr[position][j] == 5)
                outputLines.add("InValid Static Node V" + j);
        }
        if (arr[i][j] == -1) {
            position = j;

            if (arr[position][j] == 55)
                outputLines.add("InValid Mobile Node V" + j);
        }
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
            position = j;

            if (arr[position][j] == 55)
                outputLines.add("Valid Mobile Node V" + j);  
        }
    }
}

for(String outputLine : outputLines){
  System.out.println(outputLine);
}
```

Which will output:

```
Valid Static Node V1
Valid Static Node V2
Valid Static Node V3
Valid Static Node V4
InValid Static Node V5
InValid Static Node V6
Valid Static Node V7
Valid Static Node V8
Valid Static Node V9
Valid Mobile Node V10
InValid Static Node V11
InValid Mobile Node V12
InValid Static Node V16
InValid Static Node V13
Valid Static Node V14
InValid Static Node V15
InValid Static Node V17
InValid Static Node V18
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##zZZNb4IwGMfvfoonniBOggcu8@W8JXMXEi/GQxXUVixEisti@OyupRaRF8GXbGtIatt/f/yfp6WVoD3qEmdzPC48FIYwRpgeWgBBNPfwAkKGGK/2PnZgy4c0m@0wXU1ngHQhA8CUTWeivdvBEA6QdKpyAOsFeuoxmz8Qv2Q5eSqXWErLwd1ec2yRlIWZEta7m5SDmbXhi0irSEXY2eJFzKpRA6vimRWoyuQ3gRYWJSHWskpxhTWpD/QK7V5S6dreSxIw62mokj18a9YrzeVgd7Cy7ppv1ca0h1CXtEdRKe0pKEl7FkrQUlLcTyrCj38jYtgzbJcN5OE@Aj9iQcQ@MHVDfqZT9yuj470b13lD4VrMGGl6X10DEPghZtinfI4pe5f@DjQxhJM@Xg3ERWF4Ll2xNW93Ojoc0tBSOZFyIuVTPEtnkMsZyauXoEnVlMxgOIReXiFKxhzptwrDCqJkimXpBakomQwZyHG09gR5/Iq05XX56TsuTNrQAXJKjyrxdefdv7D@Tv@j@Vvdj/059tyr7n9x19y2bcq85w7tc@7lr1M0/Is5/SXLsOE1@yJdRWV/h8zdGnzICPgM5lHtLDslS8DjVnw8/gA)

---

You can also simplify your if-checks inside the nested loop a bit. For example:

```
position = j;
if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
    if (arr[position][j] == 5)
        outputLines.add("Valid Static Node V" + j);
    else if(arr[position][j] == 55)
        outputLines.add("Valid Mobile Node V" + j);
}
else if (arr[i][j] == -1) {
    if (arr[position][j] == 5)
        outputLines.add("InValid Static Node V" + j);
    else if (arr[position][j] == 55)
        outputLines.add("InValid Mobile Node V" + j);
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##tZZNj8IgEIbv/oqJpzauTXvwsn6cd5N1LyZejAe0qGClpkU3G9Pf7oJIxX5oqy4hocA7zzADgVK0R23qr4/HeYDiGIaIsEMDYLubBWQOMUdcNPuQ@LARU9aIR4QtJ1NAtpQBEMYnU9mPIujDAU6Duhyg8waerm71CsmbyclShaSjtQLc9qpj8yQT5iqY9zApA3Pvhi8jLSPlYZclXsWsO3dgZTy3BFWa/CrQ3KaciHdZhbjcntwP9AbtUVLh3j5KkrDOy1AFZ7hu1ksXl4E9wDJXV/2oVqY9hbqmPYtKaS9BKdqrUJKWkpLuqaHi@nd2nATOCPOeutwHEO74dse/CMOxuNMZ/jF0YnSN/Q8Ur6TFwLK7@hmAbRgTTkImbFw1uggjsOQUOY2JpicfCifAbMlXot9q2XBIQ0vlVMmpkk/INLWg1xayGG5p92qGLMBS9hM6hX4fvKytqdIcLe7YOaksRnIc5PtWc4wC8TqO1Ev5HfoYxk1oAbW7OXscxFj4K3ZXz98wnJEA3/CXNAo8Z/LR/peEfLL6KYHncqJd1siK@koa@qCef20MNrybjmydqNFvzPHGEVPOVljwgFkX2dmdhCeN5Hj8Aw)

---

---

Since OP later on asked for a solution without any libraries whatsoever, here an alternative approach:

```
// Loop over the diagonal
for(int diag = 0; diag < arr.length; diag++){
  String nodeType = arr[diag][diag] == 5?
                     "Static"
                    :
                     "Mobile"; // Assumes the nodeType is ALWAYS one of 5 or 55
  // Loop over the rows above the diagonal for the current column
  int node = 0;
  for(int row = 0; row < diag; row++){
    // Bitwise-OR the node with the current value
    //  0  | 0 remains 0
    //  0  | 1 becomes 1
    //  0  | -1 becomes -1
    //  1  | 1 remains 1
    //  -1 | -1 remains -1
    //  (NOTE: 1 | -1 becomes -1, but I assumed a column will never contain both a 1 and -1)
    node |= arr[row][diag];
  }
  String nodeValid = node == 1?
                      "Valid" 
                     :node == -1?
                      "Invalid"
                     :
                      null;
  // Only print the node if the column contained a 1 or -1:
  if(nodeValid != null)
    System.out.println(nodeValid + " " + nodeType + " Node V" + diag);
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##rZZNb@IwEIbP218xmxMIQpMDFyhasdIeKrVFWqquVoiDAQPuGhvlA4Qov52O7YQkhASWEqJ8eGYee15PbN7Jitjvk3/7/ZgT34dnwsT2DmAZjjgbgx@QAG8rySawQFOlH3hMzAZDIFXlBsBEMBiqd8@DDmxBN8bHFpp1cOPTufyEXT3NOaaiSzP2RbDtXo7Nk9Iwx8Dcq0lHMOds@irTIlIelgwxk3P8cgZWxHMKUIXiXwLNTYomnmWdxOXm5HyiJbRrSSfn9lqSgjVvhjpRw/@reuHgjmBXsNKju7xUL6Z9CZWlfRV1oN0EZWi3QinagbRr69v9PTxJuQS5oh4EcwoTRmZSEK6tU@lVcH3Xjbi4O23z9KAW@wanYhbMTVOtFu0GAGaDACEn9HWzpBiGzgPlNDRX6HSg@SOTTuaw@nrPsQo9WiWxz3LEOLXaKrGu74cL6uu0DsNhPnSf/nT/9kEKCnKKkkgPiz1i5vTw5NoHMsL3jDxKGt0wDj2PokRjycOFiChKM9Wj1ixqi7VEoJFSPTxooH5OSfgNR/GTBWvmU7v3@zB@WLNgnul0RXhIU0H4KcAHXjyq9mofnJzNhREdS6WKm7PZidHOWF0TGVMzNgzSkbExG1l56b3@aoF7TK/DKAzgEYieogmQSD9MkXMQVKk/liJAJIwkZk2QQcQEQ6uH2deafJj6QgGj8or13uXr8Y1w/BvTiaamA25JFYKlvS0odmnFHLsc9ChWGlVCKgkXIeftpDp7gm9g6alKOtQFm5qqMBJGumlVXVXcthvz2bSS6PC9o9mJnv2NH9BFQ4ZBQ3fARcq7Bhb@asmHpBpeVO9vqllJXzXDVMLv7nb7/Sc)

Comment: Thank you very much. it is working now. but is there any other way to solve this problem without using java.util.LinkedHashSet<String>. ?

Comment: @Ali You mean where it prints directly without saving the numbers in a set to print at the end?

Comment: Yes. i do not want to use any package to solve this problem

Comment: @Ali Ah ok. Hmm.. Will the input matrix be guarantees to only contains the numbers `0, 1, -1, 5, 55`?

Comment: Yes. 0, 1, -1, 5, 5 only this set

Comment: Yes sir. Exactly this one is required. Thank you very much for your kind support.

Comment: @Ali Np. If this helped you finding your solution, [make sure to accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/324390). :)

Comment: @Ali, it looks like you are not aware that you can accept an answer if you are the asker. It is part of protocol and etiquette to try accepting the best answer that has answered your question by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. You can check [the FAQ entry on when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can also check [how important is accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163740). "Thank you very much" in words does NOT count at all. Only acceptance of an answer and upvote count! (this comment will be deleted.)

Comment: By the way, that might be why people will not answer your questions later (this comment will be deleted).